# Disable pregenerated headers (PCH) for IntelliSense in VisualStudio for a Linux Makefile project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, precompiled-headers

I am currently working on a **Linux Makefile** project in VS2017. And in for every header file I get this error:

```
Intellisense PCH Warning: Header stop not at file scope. An intellisense PCH file was not generated
```

Doesn't matter if I have `#pragma once` or similar things or not.
Removing the `.vs` folder to regenerate the IntelliSense did also not help.
I even tried adding `/Y-` in the additional parameter field for IntelliSense.

So in short, how do I turn this off or fix it?

Comment: Hi Brain, does this issue occurs in a new Linux Makefile? If you compile this project, there have the error message or not.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Tools > options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced**

Then change **Disable Automatic Precompiled Headers** to **True**.

Also, useful might be changing **Always use fallback location** and **Do Not Warn If Fallback Location Used** to **true**.